# Why Transmission of electrical energy without wires was not practical even after Tesla's proposal

Tags: electricity

Why we couldn't transmit Electricity wirelessly even after so many proposals available proposed by Tesla ?

> Tesla tried to generate more interest in Wardenclyffe by revealing its
>   ability to transmit wireless electricity, but Morgan was not
>   interested, and the 1903 "rich man's panic" on Wall Street dried up
>   any further investment.[8][9][10] By July 1904, Morgan (and the other
>   investors) finally decided they would not provide any additional
>   financing. In May 1905, Tesla's patents on alternating current motors
>   and other methods of power transmission expired, halting royalty
>   payments and causing a severe reduction of funding to the Wardenclyffe
>   Tower. In an attempt to find alternative funding Tesla advertised the
>   services of the Wardenclyffe facility but he was met with little
>   success. By this time Tesla had also designed the Tesla turbine at
>   Wardenclyffe and produced Tesla coils for sale to various businesses.
>   [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardenclyffe_Tower)
>
> In 1891 and 1892, Tesla demonstrated the oscillatory transformer that
>   bears his name in lectures delivered before meetings of the American
>   Institute of Electrical Engineers (AIEE) in New York City" and the
>   Institute of Electrical Engineers (IEE) in London, and in a later
>   presentation titled "On Light and Other High Frequency Phenomena"
>   (Philadelphia/St. Louis; Franklin Institute in 1893), where he put
>   forward his ideas on the wireless transmission of electrical energy.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardenclyffe_Tower)

[image]

The Tesla coil wireless transmitter

Comment: We *do* transmit electrical energy, every day. We call it "radio". However, with commercial AM broadcast stations transmitting many kilowatts, and the received power being less than a milliwatt, [it's not terribly efficient](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/72509/17608). I suspect this is at the heart of the problem.

Comment: Commercially, how would you measure useage for billing.

Comment: Because Tesla never really made it work. Microwave power transmission is a working technology, but it is not enormously efficient.

Comment: @Optionparty, just the same way we charge mobile users for the service ?